# jQuery - multi level menu for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, slide

I need to make menu with multi-level sub menus for mobile.
This is dynamic menu, so I can not add more classes to html.
Menu is sliding down when I click on element which have child .sub-menu:

```
> ul.sub-menu
```

But when I want to click another (deeper) element in same node all this node menu is going to slideUp.

Here is my code:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpj2g447/2/)

**For example:**

First > 03 > (closing) > First > (03 is opened) > 03-02 > (closing) > First > 03 > (closing) > First > My node to element 03-02-02 is already opened.

Thanks for advance for your help

> **FULL SOLUTION HERE:**
>   [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpj2g447/7/)

Comment: you can stop propagation on click

Comment: but how to make this?

Comment: So, you are trying to figure out how to get the sub menu items to slide down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this to solve the issue

```
var test1 = $( '#menu-mobile-slide ul.menu li' );
    test1.on( 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var mobileMenu = $(e.target).parent().find( '> ul.sub-menu' );
        if( mobileMenu.css('display') == 'none' ) {
            mobileMenu.slideDown();
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            mobileMenu.slideUp();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but now links for example: First > 03 > 03-01 is not working :(
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpj2g447/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to bind the click events to every `a`(instead of `li`) and find the submenu to slide up/down with `siblings()` function.

You can also use `slideToggle()` to open/close submenus.
The click is prevented only if is present a sibling `ul`.

```
var test1 = $('#menu-mobile-slide li > a');
test1.on('click', function(e) {
    var mobileMenu = $(this).siblings('ul');
    if (mobileMenu.length > 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    mobileMenu.slideToggle();
});
```